# linux rdma mellanox clarification

Tags: linux, rdma

I was going through the linux/drivers/net/ethernet/mellanox/mlx4/qp.c

Got a few questions. Would really appreciate if someone can clarify:

In the function, mlx4_qp_alloc_icm,

To allocate a QP, there are 2 paths taken:

1. using the ALLOC_RES virtual command
2. using the MAP_ICM

These paths are taken based on the return value of mlx4_is_func(dev). This is true for MASTER or SLAVE which I believe is Physical Function Driver/Virtual Function Driver. So for SRIOV, it covers all cases.

The MAP_ICM portion which gets executed as part of __mlx4_qp_alloc_icm never gets called??

Am I understanding it properly? Because as per my understanding ICM needs to be allocated for all the QPs.

Please help me in understanding this.

EDIT:

Adding relevant code:

```
320 static int mlx4_qp_alloc_icm(struct mlx4_dev *dev, int qpn)
321 {
322         u64 param = 0;
323 
324         if (mlx4_is_mfunc(dev)) {
325                 set_param_l(&param, qpn);
326                 return mlx4_cmd_imm(dev, param, &param, RES_QP, RES_OP_MAP_ICM,
327                                     MLX4_CMD_ALLOC_RES, MLX4_CMD_TIME_CLASS_A,
328                                     MLX4_CMD_WRAPPED);
329         }
330         return __mlx4_qp_alloc_icm(dev, qpn);
331 }
```

http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/net/ethernet/mellanox/mlx4/icm.c#L226

```
226 static int mlx4_MAP_ICM(struct mlx4_dev *dev, struct mlx4_icm *icm, u64 virt)
227 {
228         return mlx4_map_cmd(dev, MLX4_CMD_MAP_ICM, icm, virt);
229 }
```

Thanks so much.

Best Regards,
Marc

Comment: Could you add a link to the code? I think it looks a little different: `__mlx4_qp_alloc_icm` calls `mlx4_table_get`, and `MAP_ICM` is just the opcode modifier to the `ALLOC_RES` virtual command.

Comment: Sure. Please have a look at http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/net/ethernet/mellanox/mlx4/qp.c#L320

Comment: I have pasted the code also. As you can see line 330 ends up using the opcode MLX4_CMD_MAP_ICM. Whereas line 326 uses MLX4_CMD_ALLOC_RES

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `MAP_ICM` command is privileged, and only the physical function driver is allowed to execute it. It is executed through `__mlx4_qp_alloc_icm` in the example quoted in the question when the driver is in "native" mode: neither handling a virtual function or a physical function that manages other virtual functions.

In SRIOV mode, when the driver manages a physical function that has some virtual functions, the `__mlx4_qp_alloc_icm` function is called only from within the resource tracker in `resource_tracker.c`. This module manages the allocation of ICM for all the functions it handles (virtual and physical) to prevent conflicts. The call to `__mlx4_qp_alloc_icm` specifically is in the `qp_alloc_res` function.

Comment: haggai_e, thanks so much for explaining it clearly...now i understand... thank you!